# how to create associative array in javascript

Tags: javascript, hashtable, associative-array

i am an absolute beginner learning js and node.js and i am building a simple scraper. the code is scraping multiple domains . i would like to store information such as the titles, meta tags such as description, etc for each of the the domains scraped into a hash table but i have no idea how to proceed. can you shortly explain how to do it? here you have the code

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var URL = require('url-parse');
var arr = ["http://allrecipes.com/", "http://www.gossip.fr/" ];
console.log("Visiting pages now... ");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

   setTimeout(request, 5000 * i, arr[i], function (error, response, body) {
         if(error) {
           console.log("Error: " + error);
   }
           console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
         if(response.statusCode === 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
         console.log("Page title:  " + $('title').text());
  }
});
}
```

i modify the code as you can see below but instead of storing into the hash the title for each domains scraped, it store the result just for the last domains of the array. see code below

```
    var request = require('request');
    var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    var URL = require('url-parse');
    var output = {};
    var arr = ["http://allrecipes.com/", "http://www.gossip.fr/",                "http://www.clicrbs.com.br/rs/" ];
    console.log("Visiting pages now... ");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var result = arr[i];

    setTimeout(request, 5000 * i, arr[i], function (error, response, body) {
      if(error) {
      console.log("Error: " + error);
                }
      console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
      if(response.statusCode === 200) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(body);
      console.log("Page title:  " + $('title').text());
                                       }
      {
    output[result] = {error: error, title: $('title').text(), status:      response.statusCode} 

  }
});
}
```

Comment: JavaScript does not have associate arrays. Are you referring to [EcmaScript 6 Map](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-maps-in-depth)?

Comment: Pro tip: use let instead of var. This can save you from a surprise later on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `let` in place of `var`. That way you create a new `let` variable in each iteration, instead of overwriting the old `var`.

Correct:

```js
let output = {}
let a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    let result = a[i]; setTimeout(x => output[result] = i, i*5)
}

setTimeout(() => document.write(JSON.stringify(output)), 20)
```

Incorrect:

```js
let output = {}
let a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    var result = a[i]; setTimeout(x => output[result] = i, i*5)
}

setTimeout(() => document.write(JSON.stringify(output)), 20)
```

You can read more about `let` and [lexicographic scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules_2) on Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: thanks Bjartur, much appriciated. i wasn't aware of "let". it fixed the issue

Comment: yes but  i am working on the code now cause i am having some other issues cause the end result of the hash is wrong.                             { 'http://allrecipes.com/': { domains: 'Allrecipes | Food, friends, and recipe inspiration' },
  'http://www.gossip.fr/': { domains: 'Gossip - Retrouvez toutes les actualités people, news et potins sur les stars et célébrités, ainsi que les derniers buzz du net et infos sur la télé réalité' },